# TFS: Exception calling "SetRight" with "2" argument(s): "Could not obtain the user information."

Tags: powershell, tfs

I have a release definition in TFS with 2 tasks. One of them passes perfectly, while the other throws an exception, though both have very smimlar configuration.

The successful task configuration:

```
CopyFile Task
Source: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/XXX Build Definition/drop
Machines $(WebServers)
Admin Login: server\user
Password: Password
Protocol: HTTP
Destination Folder: C:\DestFolder

Variables: WebServers: MyServer
```

The failing task configuration:

```
RunPowerShellOnRemoteComputer Task
Machines $(WebServers)
Admin Login: server\user
Password: Password
Protocol: HTTP

PowerShell Script: C:\...\script.ps1

Variables: WebServers: MyServer
```

When running the second task I receive this exception:

> Exception calling "SetRight" with "2" argument(s): "Could not obtain
>   the user information."   CategoryInfo :NotSpecified: (:) [],
>   MethodInvocationException   FullyQualifiedErrorId :Exception   --->
>   System.Management.Automation.RemoteException: Exception calling
>   "SetRight" with "2" argument(s): "Could not obtain the user
>   information."
>       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.Deployment.Deployment.PowershellExecutor.Invoke(String
>   errorContextMessage, Boolean writeResultToLog, Boolean isCancellable)
>       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.Deployment.Deployment.RemoteDeploymentHelper.InstallServiceInternal(String
>   serviceSourcePath, String serviceName, String destinationFileName)
>       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.Deployment.Deployment.RemoteDeploymentHelper.InstallService(String
>   serviceSourcePath, String serviceName, String destinationFileName)
>       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.Deployment.Deployment.DeploymentClient.d__24.MoveNext()
>   ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Management.Automation.RemoteException: Exception calling
>   "SetRight" with "2" argument(s): "Could not obtain the user
>   information."<---
>        Deployment status for machine 'bgsovswops.eu.hpecorp.net:5985' : 'Failed'  ##[error], MethodInvocationException\r\n
>   FullyQualifiedErrorId :Exception\r\n"}};]
>        ##[error]System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: Failed to install
>   'VisualStudioRemoteDeployer3e199746-ae71-4ba0-a2ef-f5ce8f25a631' from
>   service executable path VisualStudioRemoteDeployer.exe . Consult the
>   logs below:  Exception calling "SetRight" with "2" argument(s): "Could
>   not obtain the user information."   CategoryInfo :NotSpecified: (:)
>   [], MethodInvocationException   FullyQualifiedErrorId :Exception
>   ---> System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: Failed to install 'VisualStudioRemoteDeployer3e199746-ae71-4ba0-a2ef-f5ce8f25a631' from
>   service executable path VisualStudioRemoteDeployer.exe . Consult the
>   logs below:  Exception calling "SetRight" with "2" argument(s): "Could
>   not obtain the user information."   CategoryInfo :NotSpecified: (:)
>   [], MethodInvocationException   FullyQualifiedErrorId :Exception
>
> ```
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineBase.Invoke(IEnumerable
> ```
>
> input)
>       at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Worker.ConstructPipelineAndDoWork(Runspace
>   rs, Boolean performSyncInvoke)
>       at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Worker.CreateRunspaceIfNeededAndDoWork(Runspace
>   rsToUse, Boolean isSync)
>       at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvokeHelper[TInput,TOutput](PSDataCollection`1
>   input, PSDataCollection`1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings)
>       at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvoke[TInput,TOutput](PSDataCollection`1
>   input, PSDataCollection`1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings)
>       at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Handlers.LegacyVSTSPowerShellHost.VSTSPowerShellHost.Main(String[]
>   args)

When I go to the remote machine, I succesfully execute the 'Invoke-Expression' on the C:...\script.ps1.

Also, I successfully connect from the local machines' powerscript console to the remote machine.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Please include the **domain** in the username variable. If it’s not domain environment, it should be the machine name.

So, just try to update the UPN user name format to **DOMAIN\Username** or **MACHINENAME\Username** format.

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked immediately. It is strange, but not too much documentation on this. It seems the one just has to know it somehow.

Comment: Also, the parameter MACHINENAME must not contain machine FQDN, but only machine name.

Answer (score 0):

### Check NetLogon Windows Service

The target server that I was deploying to reported this error. I already had the username for the *PowerShell on Target Machines* task set to use full **DOMAIN\Username**, per [Andy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44130188/3063884).

It turned out that the machine's NetLogon service had not started properly when the machine booted, due to it running on an abnormally busy VSphere cluster.

A reboot of the machine ensured that the NetLogon Windows Service, and its dependent services were all started, following which a redeploy succeeded.